# Объявление методов в javascript

Tags: ооп, javascript

Как правильнее делать: объявлять методы в теле конструктора или же через прототип?
С одной стороны, объявление метода в теле позволяет реализовать подобие `private` членов:

```
function A(val){
    var prop = val;
    this.getValue = function(){
        return prop;
    }
    this.setValue = function(val){
        prop = val;
    }
}
```

А с другой стороны, возникает вопрос, а не будет ли объявление методов в теле заполнять память, так как каждый раз при создании нового объекта методы для него будут определяться заново?

Comment: Здесь проблема не только в памяти а и в том, что, если использовать прототип, можно

Answer (score 2):

мне лень заниматься копипастом:

- [Getters & Setters в Javascript](http://habrahabr.ru/post/66242/)
- [Геттеры и сеттеры в Javascript](http://habrahabr.ru/post/108295/)